# What is the meaning of columns in the JMH result table?

Tags: jmh

I don't find anything on the web about it from [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/6cc1450c6a0f/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/results/Result.java),
Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of ops/us, Cnt, Score, Error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- ops/us - operations (benchmark method executions) per microsecond
- Cnt - total number of trials (forks*iterations)
- Score - benchmark result
- Error - standard error value. Means how much different trials results differ

Also:

- thrpt - Throughput mode (how much full benchmark method executions were made in a trial)
- avgt - Average Time mode (how much measuring units took benchmark method execution on average)